# using dataframe to groupby() with datetimeindex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have a DF with a datetimeindex (for example):

```
Date_Time            C_1
2018-09-13 9:20:00  69.45
2018-09-13 9:30:00  69.44
2018-09-13 9:40:00  69.33
2018-09-13 9:50:00  69.34
2018-09-13 10:00:00 69.36
2018-09-14 9:20:00  69.45
2018-09-14 9:30:00  69.44
2018-09-14 9:40:00  69.33
2018-09-14 9:50:00  69.34
2018-09-14 10:00:00 69.36
```

I am trying to do a `groupby()`, grouping by day doing the following:

```
#finding the days with in the group for filter
unique_days = pd.Series(np.unique(df.index.date))

#apply the groupby()
df.groupby(unique_days).groups
```

however, this returns an empty dic... meaning something is not working correctly.
`unique_days` is returning what you would expect.

```
0      2018-09-13
1      2018-09-14
2      2018-09-17
3      2018-09-18
4      2018-09-19
          ...    
265    2019-10-10
266    2019-10-11
267    2019-10-14
268    2019-10-15
269    2019-10-16
Length: 270, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem, all you need to do is the following :

`df.groupby(df.index.date)`

I clearly tried to over complicate the situation.